# crossJoining two data frames without repeating values

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two dataframes

```
DataFrame1 <-  data.frame(StudentId = c(1:20), Subject = c(rep("Algebra", 4), rep("Geometry", 4), rep("English", 4), rep("Zoology", 4), rep("Botany", 4)), CGPA = c(random::randomNumbers(20, 70, 100, 1)), Country = c(rep("USA", 4), rep("UK", 4), rep("Germany", 4), rep("France", 4), rep("Japan", 4)))
```

and

```
DataFrame2 <-  data.frame(StudentId = c(1:10), State = c(rep("NYC", 2), rep("Illinois", 2), rep("Texas", 2), rep("Virginia", 2), rep("Florida", 2)), Age = c(random::randomNumbers(10, 16, 20, 1)), Gender = c(rep("Male", 3), rep("Female", 3), rep("Male", 2), rep("Female", 2)))
```

I can merge the above two using inner join as

```
merge(DataFrame1, DataFrame2)
```

How to merge as cross Joining two data frames without repeating values?

Answer (score 1):

Try `merge(DataFrame1, DataFrame2, all = T)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for cross join..

knitr::kable(merge(x = DataFrame1, y = DataFrame2, by = NULL))